# Avoid ASP.NET special behavior of Ajax controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a form where the user can ajaxly change a lot of the information using modal popups. I am using Ajaxtoolkit and standard ASP.NET Ajax controls (that is, scriptmanager, updatepanel, etc.)

When a user is hitting the back button the user is going through all the stages of changes the user has made. I would like to avoid that. I would like that if PAGE1 is calling to PAGE2 and even though PAGE2 is radically changed using Ajax, hitting the browser's 'back' button will take the user back to PAGE1 directly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The browser back button does not get the page from server, but rather from the browser cache. So there are two ways of handling this situation:

1. This method can make us to call the previous page from the server instead of the cache:

   ```
   <body onUnload = "DoSomethingHere()"> ... </body>
   <script language = "javascript">
       DoSomethingHere() {
           window.location.href = "URL of the previous page";
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. This way we will prevent the back button action:

   ```
   function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
   setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
   window.onunload = function(){null};
   ```